# CSS defined style not always abode in Codename One

Tags: css, codenameone

In my Codename One app the styling is defined in css. Namely the side menu which I styled based on [this great video tutorial](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-create-gorgeous-sidemenu.html). So I have a style defined as follows :

```
SideMenuTagLine {
cn1-derive: "SideCommand";
text-align: right;
padding-left: 0mm;
padding-right: 0mm;
padding-top: 1mm;
padding-bottom: 0mm;
margin-right: 3mm;
font-family: "native:ItalicLight"; 
font-size: 3mm; 
}
```

When I tested the tagline showed in Italic, but then I worked further on the css to add other styles and all of a sudden the tagline lost its Italic (simulator and real device).

To make it reappear I have to delete the myTheme.css.res file. But again when I make changes to a css style (not SideMenuTagLine nor SideCommand), the tagline Italic gets lost. Maybe other stylings are also lost but I did not notice.

Here is the previews that I get when the res file is first generated (starting from no existing myTheme.css.res file). One may notice that the `KmLabelProgress` alignment changes between the unselected and the selected tabs although I did not change it.  :
[image: First generated res file]

Then if I change anything in the css file (eg : color for a selector) I get the following generated res file. In this case the afore mentionned alignment changes do not occur :
[image: Generated res file after modifications in the css file]

*Please note : this is the behaviour too in the latest (3.7.3) CN1 plugin version (as in the previous version).*

What can I do to be sure the css styles that I defined in the css file are applied ?

Any help appreciated,

Edit October 9th 2017 :
Here is the beginning of the stack trace that I get when I open the generated res file with the designer from the command line :

```
2017-10-09 10:37:09.388:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.0.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2017-10-09 10:37:09.441:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started             
SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000 STARTING
oct. 09, 2017 10:37:09 AM org.jdesktop.application.LocalStorage getId
AVERTISSEMENT: unspecified resource Application.id using ResourceEditorApp
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager(KeyboardFocusManager.java:216)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.processCurrentLightweightRequests(KeyboardFocusManager.java:2621)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.retargetFocusEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:2946)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4752)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
```

*Please note : the full stack trace is longer than the allowed length on SO.*

Comment: Can you narrow down a specific change that causes the italic to get lost? Can you review the generated res file in the designer or try to manipulate styles in runtime with the simulator style editor to see what might be triggering this?

Comment: Thanks Shai for your support. Removing the `cn1-derive` directive did not change anything : when I add or modify another style (with regard to padding, margin, font) the `SideTagLine` Italic gets lost (but not the derived color which remains white). Modifying again `SideTagLine` makes the Italic reappear again. I keep you posted if I can find something with the generated res file.

Comment: The component inspector does not let me open any theme styles : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.getTheme(EditableResources.java:1845)
 at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorApp.main(ResourceEditorApp.java:211)`

Comment: The generated res file cannot be opened in the designer (error but nothing shown in the popup dialog) but the theme.res can. If I delete the generated res file, then all css defined styles are applied. But then if I change a padding somewhere then all styles are lost (except the font colors). So it looks like there is a directive in the css file which is causing problem.

Comment: Even after commenting all the css directives the generated res file cannot be opened in the designer (Error popup that reads blank).

Comment: That's a big problem. Make sure your plugin is up to date to the latest as we changed some things in the file format. Try running the designer from command line to see the error logs as explained here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-track-designer-guibuilder-issues.html

Comment: I eventually deleted the xml file as well as the res/myTheme.css folder. Now the res file can be opened. The res/myTheme.css folder hasn't been recreated. However it does not resolve the issue with the italic, since I still have to detelete the generated res file to get the latest style changes.

Comment: Uncheck the File -> XML Team Model option in the designer tool.  That should solve the need to delete. What does the CSS generate in the res file?

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding the XML Team Model option, I had forgotten this! The CSS generates all the styles. But in the designer style preview list, when I select "selected" some styles are changing their preview icon whereas they shouldn't because I did not define them. If I change a style color in the CSS, save it, and bring it back to its original color, then the res file is regenerated with italic lost. I'll edit my question so that you can see.

Comment: How is the theme different internally. Maybe the CSS changed something basic related to a derived property. If you open the entries before/after what specifically changed?

Comment: Ok, so In the font tab, `True Type native:MainLight, True Type Size Millimeters 4,2` becomes `True Type , True Type Size Medium 12`. So `True Type` gets lost.

Comment: That seems like a bug in the CSS generation, I'll ask Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shai indicated, this was a but in the CSS generation related to native fonts.  I have fixed this bug and released a new CSS plugin (v.1.1.4).  To update, simply download the latest cn1css-ant-task.jar into your project's lib directory.

https://github.com/shannah/cn1-css/releases/tag/1.1.4